# How to put variable in route url in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the routing , I want to apply test data key having name '**pName**' which is already stored inside fixture folder

```
Testdata.json:
{
    "pName" : "ABC",
}
```

Set the **Testdata** fixture in before block of a spec:

```
 before(function(){
        cy.fixture('Testdata').then(function(testdata){
            this.testdata = testdata;
        })
    })
```

**Test Case using Route:**

```
cy.server()
cy.route('GET','/a/b/c/'+this.testdata.pName+'/0/50','fixture:/FolderA/FileA')
```

Current O/P ---> TypeError : Cannot read property 'pName' of undefined

Expected O/P ---> should route on '/a/b/c/ABC/0/50'

Comment: This might be because of the promise  used in before lifecycle. this.testdata is not set before the test is called.

Comment: Working fine . Thanks!